# Get elements in multidimensional array if the internal array has more than X elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Using javascript, what is the cleaner way to get only the array elements with a length > 2:
For example, I have this array:

```
const myArray = [ [1,2,2,2], [1,5,7,8,2,0,2,3,5], [1,3], [4], [1,2,6,8] ];
```

I'm using a nasty but functional `for` to do it. Like:

```
for(let i=0; i<myArray.lenght; i++) {
  if (myArray[i].lenght > 2) {
    myfilteredarray.push(myArray);
  }
}
```

What is a cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```js
const myArray = [ [1,2,2,2], [1,5,7,8,2,0,2,3,5], [1,3], [4], [1,2,6,8] ];
const filtered = myArray.filter(arr => arr.length > 2);
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

just add:

```js
const myArray = [ [1,2,2,2], [1,5,7,8,2,0,2,3,5], [1,3], [4], [1,2,6,8] ];

const newArr = myArray.filter(item => item.length > 2);

console.log(newArr) // result [[1,2,2,2], [1,5,7,8,2,0,2,3,5], [1,2,6,8]]
```